# Поздравляем Sharon cо 100000!

Tags: обсуждение

Совсем недавно [Sharon](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/180132/sharon) получила стотысячное очко репутации, став тем самым первым участником нашего сообщества, достигшим этой вехи.

Мы поздравляем Sharon с этим достижением и надеемся, что впереди ещё немало интересных вопросов и полезных ответов!

### [image: Поздравляем!]

Предлагаем присоединиться к поздравлениям под этим сообщением.

Answer (score 10):

Конечно же, невозможно не поддержать добрые слова!
Это примечательное событие произошло не просто "совсем недавно", оно произошло в особенный день — 1 сентября.

Мне было интересно, отчасти даже завидно, поэтому я наблюдала за ростом репутации *Sharon* — и не упустила этот момент.
Менять ничего не буду, просто повторю свой [поздравительный комментарий](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461904/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9/461907?noredirect=1#comment476729_461907).

> Поздравляю Вас, Sharon, с самой высокой (и заслуживающей самого высокого уважения!) репутацией на сайте. Снимаю все шляпы и все вообразимые и невообразимые — все! — головные уборы. Кланяюсь вашему опыту и вашим знаниям. P. S. Первое сентября — это знаменательный день (во всех отношениях).

Мне всегда казалось, что я неплохо знаю русский язык. Работа на форуме показала, что я ошибалась, что родной язык достоин того, чтобы изучать его и после окончания школы.
И в этом немалая заслуга Sharon. Спасибо!
Присоединяюсь. **УРА!**

P. S. Мне *кажется*, что в заголовке лучше использовать предлог "со" (со 100000; с чем? — со ста тысячами).

Comment: Римма,  еще раз спасибо лично вам за поздравление, Конечно, я помню, что вы меня поздравили именно 1 сентября, и это было особенно приятно.

Answer (score 7):

**Большое спасибо за поздравление!**

Наш форум – это что-то особенное, почти мистическое. Расстаться с ним трудно,  потому что другого такого нет. В нем **гармоничное сочетание** строгих ответов и незримо присутствующей любви к языку.

**Эта любовь у каждого своя,** так что иногда мне хочется спросить у давно знакомых мне людей: а вы что любите, почему вы здесь? И удивительно то, что я этого действительно не знаю. Это – тайна, которая притягивает и волнует.

**Если люди уходят, то я тоже не могу их понять.** Я скучаю по ним, мне хочется, чтобы они вернулись. И очень люблю, когда к нам приходят новые участники. Мы живем в разных уголках огромной страны, но почти каждый день собираемся **в этой виртуальной гостиной,  в нашем интернет-клубе.** Здесь пространство воспринимается иначе – даже странно подумать, что некоторые из нас, возможно,  живут в одном городе.  Нет, такого не может быть, мне легче представить, что мы на разных планетах.

Я думаю, что не все из нас догадываются, что **наш форум – это настоящая сокровищница,** и  если  уж не теории, то практического материала  точно.  Только здесь лингвисты-теоретики могут услышать **живой голос времени,** наши вопросы и ответы, а по сути,  наше знание и наше понимание родного языка.

**По значимости** я приравняла бы форум к Нацкорпусу, без которого сейчас совершенно невозможно обойтись при изучении грамматики и правописания. Как люди воспринимали правила, каков был общий уровень знаний общества на текущий момент – вот что здесь найдут будущие историки. А еще прекрасная платформа, легкий поиск нужного материала – всё это  преимущества нашего ресурса.

В заключение в качестве [примера](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462874/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) («Вал» и «волна» — родственны ли слова?) я приведу **недавнее мнение о форуме и свой ответ** (правда, обращался наш гость не ко мне).

–  По видимому сайт направлен, в большей степени, **на правописание общепринятого, нежели на изучение, либо понимание Русских слов.** Мне, как раз, интересно понимание и осознание. **Ведь Русские слова, нужно и слышать, и видеть, и осознавать.** По сему, ещё раз, Благо дарю вам за помощь и вероятно покидаю этот сайт. Может быть, вы сумеете рекомендовать сайт, нужной мне направленности? Буду вам, очень, признателен.

– Я попробую тоже вам ответить. На этом форуме обсуждаются разные вопросы русского языка, в том числе происхождение и значение русских слов. В то же время здесь приветствуются **сведения, изложенные в проверенных источниках и выводы, основанные на таких знаниях.** Понимание и осознание слов, как я полагаю, без этого невозможно. Да, язык надо чувствовать и понимать, **но и уважать его тоже надо,** поэтому **правописание не менее важно**, и мы уделяем этому много внимания. Мы также приветствуем грамотно записанные вопросы, в том числе с точки зрения пунктуации. Будем рады помочь вам в этом плане.

Вот такой получился диалог.

**Еще раз большое спасибо всем!**

Comment: Sharon, извините, я _чуть_ изменила Ваш ответ — просто добавила ссылку. Ведь по прошествии некоторого куска времени будет трудно понять — о каком вопросе, о чьих мнениях идет речь. (Не нравится — "откатите".)

Comment: Всё нормально, спасибо!

Comment: Поздравляю вас, Sharon!!! ;)

Comment: Спасибо, Артем! А я тогда поздравлю вас с Новым годом. Будем надеяться, что наш  "виртуальный клуб" будет и дальше радовать и нас, и наших гостей интересными вопросами и ответами. Счастья вам и успехов во всем!

Comment: @Sharon  Приветствую вас!  Давно не заходил на Мету. А я даже фантазировал на тему: "А что если эта Shаron живет у меня за стенкой? А вдруг мы с ней здороваемся через день, когда встречаемся у подъезда или в магазине?" :)

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Спасибо, Александр, за поздравление! Очень приятно ваше внимание. Тоже давно не заходила на Мету. Так, значит, за стенкой, в магазине, у подъезда? Забавно! А вот вы для меня совершенно виртуальный  персонаж:  в метро, наверное,  не на эскалаторе спускаетесь, а выходите прямо из колонны, а позвать вас можно, только постучав три раза по дереву и сказав «джаф! джаф! джаф!» (Или как там ваше настоящее имя?):)

Comment: Так вы  правда отзываетесь!  Вы меня слышите?  Вас вроде бы не было на форуме...

Answer (score 6):

Шаронушка разлюбезная - так держать!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хватай для поддержания тонуса - чтоб не слишком расслабляться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо!!!  Помню о вас всегда и скучаю по вас. Вы удивительный человек, как-то я не сразу об этом догадалась. Жаль, что вы мало отвечаете на вопросы, очень не хватает вашей совершенно неповторимой экспрессии, вашей художественно-разговорной речи, такой яркой и эмоциональной. Вашего задора, огонька, тепла. Не знаю, как другим, но мне не хватает.

Comment: Уау! Сейчас увидела, что якобы марш - это ж Северянин, "Ананасы в шампанском"! А? Ну, чуть сбиты 2--4-я строки...